# For a real square matrix $S$, what can be said about $Tr(S^2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, trace, symmetric-matrices

For a real square matrix $S$ with all eigenvalues on the imaginary axis, what can be said about $Tr(S^2)$? Since all eigenvalues of $S$ are on imaginary axis, $Tr(S)=0$ but I was wondering if anything more I can find about $Tr(S^2)$.

I know the following property is associated with the trace of the product of two positive semi-definite matrices $X\geq{0},Y\geq{0}$,

$Tr(X^{T}Y)\leq{Tr(X)}\lambda_{max}({Y})$ where $\lambda_{max}(Y)$ denotes the maximum eigenvalue of $Y$. Since $S$ is not specified whether positive semi-definite or not, I cannot use the property. Is there any other property that I can use to say anything about $Tr(S^2)$?

Comment: Why do you say that $tr(S^2)=0$? Take $S=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $tr(S^2)=-2\neq 0$.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. I only meant what can be said about $Tr(S^2)$?

Comment: I think I found an answer and correct me if I am wrong and please let me know if you find anything new. Since $S$ is real and can be put in the real Jordan form $S=M^{-1}KM$ and therefore $Tr(S^2)=Tr(K^2)$. Since $K$ is a block diagonal matrix with each block being in the form $K=\begin{bmatrix}0 & \pm{\sigma}\\{\mp}{\sigma} & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $K^2=\begin{bmatrix}-\sigma^2 & 0\\0 & -\sigma^2\end{bmatrix}$ and from which $Tr(K^2)=-2\sigma^2<0$.

Comment: If $i\lambda$ is an eigen value of $S$, then $-\lambda^2$is an eigen value of $S^2$. The trace being sum of eigen values means $\text{Tr}(S^2)=\sum_{k}\left(-\lambda_k^2\right)<0$. So the trace will be a negative number. Of course $\lambda=0$ also lies on the imaginary axis and it will change the result a bit.